# Poor Rendering Performance Scrolling Formatted Textblock (Surface WinRT)

Tags: c#, performance, windows-runtime, scrollviewer, textblock

I have code that parses a source code file and applies color formatting to various text elements (keywords, operators, etc..) and returns the results to a Textblock embedded in a Scrollviewer.

The issue I'm having is incredibly poor performance at the **end** of a scroll event i.e., the page scroll stops moving and the application lags for 3 seconds to process the next touch input. If I continue to scroll through the page without letting the ScrollViewer stop, the performance is smooth. I've confirmed there is no performance issue when not formatting the text coloring by just loading the source text into the Textblock, so I'm assuming there's underlying UI logic I'm not aware of when the app attempts to render the Textblock after a touch event.

My solution of formatting the colors is parsing the text and returning a list of [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run.aspx) objects and adding them to the Textblock [Inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property:

```
Textblock SourceContents; // UI Defined Textblock
...

protected async void LoadSourceCode(StorageFile file)
{
    String sourceCode = await ReadFile(file);
    FileLoader.Format(sourceCode);
    List<Run> formattedText = FileLoader.FormattedText;
    SourceContents.Inlines.AddRange(formattedText);
}
```

Is there a better way of handling the problem and is there underlying rendering logic dealing with a textblock with numerous Inlines?

Comment: My recommendation is that you use a virtualized ItemsControl for this.

Comment: Try to use CacheMode="BitmapCache" on your TextBlock, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.bitmapcache

Comment: I'll take a look at ItemsControl and see what I can do to apply it to my case.

Comment: I did enable the CacheMode, and it did clear up the jerky performance issues, but the text was incredibly blurred.